# Mystifying command not found at login

Tags: linux, bash, arch-linux, login

I've just set up Arch Linux (not my first time). Everything installed correctly but when I login (X isn't installed yet) I see:

```
Arch Linux 3.8.4-1-ARCH (tty1)

mgoszcz2 login: root
Password:
Last login: Thu Mar 28 21:47:57 on tty1
-bash: en_IE.UTF-8: command not found
[root@mgoszcz2 ~]#
```

Anyone knows what's causing this? Any way to fix this?

Comment: Look through your shell initialization files for the line where you have incorrectly tried to set your locale.

Comment: I looked through `/etc/bash.bashrc` `/etc/issue` & `/etc/motd` and didn't find anything.. Anywhere else I should look?

Comment: See the Arch Wiki [bash article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash#Invocation) for details on the relevant files...

Comment: Thanks. I'll close the question once stack exchange allows me to :)

Comment: If you found the issue, you can answer your own question: it may help someone else with a similar problem.

Comment: I'll but since I have below 10 reputation I need to wait 10 hours :o

Comment: You have more than 10 now :) Welcome aboard!

Comment: Sorry... Sleeping is an important part of my life

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks jasonwryan. It seems that by accident file `/etc/locale.conf` contained

```
en_IE.UTF-8
```

instead of, correct

```
LANG=en_IE.UTF-8
```

Thanks a million.

Comment: Had the same problem except mine was LANG=en_IE.UTF-8 UTF-8
thanx